# Microstack libvirt how to enable TCP listening mode

Tags: microstack

Microstack  was setup as cluster with 2 computing nodes.

Version: microstack  ussuri    222    latest/beta    canonical✓  devmode

But libvirtd is default shipped only with sockets.

Change the configuration file:

/var/snap/microstack/common/libvirt/libvirtd.conf

to

```
listen_tls = 0
listen_tcp = 1
tcp_port = "16509"
LIBVIRTD_ARGS="--listen"
unix_sock_rw_perms = "0770"
unix_sock_dir = "/var/snap/microstack/common/run/libvirt"
auth_unix_ro = "none"
auth_unix_rw = "none"
auth_tcp = "none"
```

and restart the service did not help. How TCP listening can be enabled that remote connections are possible in this specific snapd environment ?

Error Message:

```
virsh -c qemu+tcp://node1/system list
error: failed to connect to the hypervisor
error: unable to connect to server at 'node1:16509': Connection refused
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue and finally tracked it down. Firstly there was a recent change in libvirt that results in it ignoring the port / listen arguments in libvirtd.conf [reference](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1741403). After some digging I noticed the requisite .socket files were not present in `/etc/systemd/system/`. To resolve the issue copy the following files:

```
/snap/microstack/222/usr/lib/systemd/system/libvirtd-tcp.socket
/snap/microstack/222/usr/lib/systemd/system/libvirtd.socket
```

to `/etc/systemd/system/`. Next you'll need to make a few minor edits. In both libvirtd.socket and libvirtd-tcp.socket you'll change two lines:

```
#Before=libvirtd.service
Before=snap.microstack.libvirtd.service

#Service=libvirtd.service
Service=snap.microstack.libvirtd.service
```

and in libvirtd-tcp

remove or comment the line `SocketGroup=libvirt from libvirtd.socket`
next you'll run `systemctl daemon-reload`, `systemctl enable libvirtd-tcp.socket` and lastly `systemctl enable libvirtd.socket`. Once that is done on any and all microstack compute / controller nodes reboot them and you should be able to live migrate instances between hosts.

Comment: Thanks it goes further now, but Live Migration stopped with: libvirt.libvirtError: internal error: Attempt to migrate guest to the same host 86754f14-cdce-b34e-8f4a-cf799d48ef85